# How to prevent a Beep sound if global keyboard shortcut is pressed in the other application?

Tags: cocoa, keyboard, osx-snow-leopard, shortcut, hotkeys

**Mac OS X 10.6 — Cocoa**

I'm using global event monitor for displaying status item menu using custom keyboard shortcut:

`globalEventMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event)
{
    if ([event keyCode] == kVK_F12)
    {
        [self handleGlobalShortcut];
        // How to prevent system beep?
    }
}];`

This solution is working but the system generates a beep sound every time when user presses F12 and *active* application doesn't respond to this key event.

Is there any way to prevent an active application from beeping every time I use a global shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your event monitor, you need to activate your app so that *it* will receive the key event.

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

Otherwise, the event will be passed to the current active application (which will beep).

EDIT: It looks like this won't work.

According to the docs *"you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event from being delivered to its original target application"*.

So Snow Leopard's new `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` API is not suitable for handling hot keys.  You will need to continue to use the old Carbon `RegisterEventHotKey` API.  Fortunately, this API is compatible with 64-bit Cocoa on Snow Leopard.

Comment: It's beeping anyway :) Could you please provide some lines of code? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your additions Darren. I'm marking your answer as the right one. Well deserved :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems impossible. Beeping is the default behavior of [NSResponder noResponderFor]. So an application beep unless it override that behavior by adding a last responder, which is unlikely doable from outside the application.