# Cocoa/Carbon: catch global hotkey when key is kept pressed (held down)

Tags: cocoa, events, hotkeys, pressed

Using `InstallApplicationEventHandler` and `RegisterEventHotKey` from Carbon framework, I'm able to catch whatever key I want.

On the contrary I can't find a way to handle correctly the event when a key is held down (kept pressed). I mean, when I held down a key, `RegisterEventHotKey` responds like if I have pressed and then released the key; I want it, instead, to send the "event" continuously until the key is released.

What I really want to achieve, to be precise, when a key is kept pressed is this:

as soon as the key is pressed and held down I want that `InstallApplicationEventHandler` and `RegisterEventHotKey` create an event but not only once (as I have now) but every x milliseconds or so until the key is released.

The particular keys that I'm considering are **not** modifier keys.

Can you help me? I'm really becoming crazy on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe start firing a timer every 0.25 seconds or something that checks to see if the appropriate keys are still down.  If they are, re-invoke the action.  Otherwise, invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an event tap; `RegisterEventHotKey` isn't flexible enough to do what you want.  Check out [Event Taps Testbench](http://pfiddlesoft.com/eventtapstestbench/) and the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Or, in Mac OS X 10.6 and later, use the block-based equivalents. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunatly I'm not a programmer and I am too noob with cocoa to implement such solutions. I don't know where exactly to look and where to start from. I solved monitoring (with RegisterEventHotKey) even the release of the key and using a timer. I know that the solution I have adopted isn't elegant, but I've not enough knowledge to implement those solutions. Is there any tutorial or something noobproof to be able to achieve that?

Comment: @Andrea3000: Don't sell yourself short. Just do it; if it doesn't work, try to figure out why not. Google will usually help you with any error messages, and if you can't find anything, you will, by that point, be able to ask a specific and thorough question on Stack Overflow about whatever problem you encounter. The way to lose your “noob” status isn't to give up because “I am too noob”; it is to tackle the problem, solve it, and learn from it.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: Yes, you are right. Unfortunately at the moment I'm really busy with the master degree at the university therefore I have to postpone the learning :) As soon as I will have enough spare time, I'll try to implement such a solution, I promise ;)

Comment: @Peter Hosey: you effectively CAN'T use that 10.6 API because it implies a NSBeep as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880555/how-to-prevent-a-beep-sound-if-global-keyboard-shortcut-is-pressed-in-the-other-a and there is no way to prevent it.

Comment: @valexa: Interesting. So it sounds like an event tap is the only way to do this.