# How to exit a loop when user presses Command + period on the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My utility app performs text editing operations on another app.
After the user sets parameters in a NSPanel and clicks OK, the NSPanel closes and a while loop is iterated that performs the necessary text editing in the target app.

I would like to offer the user the option to halt the operation using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.
I'm not sure how to check if the user is holding down keys while the loop is iterating.

The while loop simplified.

```
- (IBAction)fileNameTrimAppend:(id)sender {
    [self activateTargetApp];  // applescript that brings target app to front
    [self openFileRenameDialog]; // applescript to open the file naming dialog

   // set variables to use in the loop from the user input
    [self close];   // close the input NSPanel

    while ([self fileRenameDialogOpen]) {  // applescript returns false when editing is done       
       if (command +"." is held down){  // need help here
             return;
          }

       // text mod is done here.
       // paste the mod text into target app field
       // move to the next field for editing
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that these are two different processes, you can use `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` to observe the keyboard.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880555/1804403) for a similar discussion.

Comment: Sorry Skotch, I thought I did.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you intend for the app to hang (and beach ball) while it's working, you'll need to break the work up into smaller chunks, and process a chunk at a time, letting the runloop process events in between. You can use -performSelector:afterDelay:0 to schedule the next chunk to run.

If you do intend to block everything while it's working, you'll need to look into running the runloop reentrantly yourself. The runloop docs should have some more information, though you may need to dig a bit: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html